# Regarding using MetaTrader 4 with PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux

I am using PlayOnLinux for using MetaTrader 4, a Windows application. 
But the problem is that I have to install MT4 every time to open it. 
Is there any option to open MT4 easily?

I am installing MetaTrader 4 every time to use it.
MT4= Meta trader 4

Answer (score 0):

yes there is.

1. The solution is to first install the play on linux application.
2. Go to your broker and download the mt4 application.
3. Go to your play on linux application and follow the steps required to install a non-listed program.
4. preferred is the wine 3.0.3 when choosing the version of wine in your play on linux.
5. Your mt4 will now be installed onto your linux machine but after closing you will have challenges opening your mt4 using play on linux.
6. Go to your browser and install wine. I prefer you use the following commands found on this website:

https://www.linuxslaves.com/2018/09/how-to-install-wine-303-stable-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

7.You will be able to reopen your mt4 by going to your home folder and looking for play on linux virtual drives where your mt4 application was installed.
E.g mine was in (play on linux virtual drive's/mt4/drive c/program files/FBS Trader 4)

8.OPEN YOUR YOUR TERMINAL.EXE FILE USING PREVIOUSLY INSTALLED WINE.

HOPE THIS HELPS.